# How to use the Fetch API with TLS certificate?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, client-certificates, fetch-api

In the context of a service worker running in background and triggered by a `push` event, with Chrome (Android) not being launched, I'm trying to send an HTTP request with a TLS client certificate using the `fetch` API.

When Chrome is launched the request succeeds, the TLS certificate already having been sent to the server. But the request fails in the case described above with the following error: `"failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED"`.

I've tried using the `Request` options `{credentials: 'include'}` and `{ credentials: 'origin' }` but unsuccessfully.

What is the proper way of using the fetch API with a TLS client certificate ?